# Bitrix24 How to write custom event handler

Tags: bitrix

I want to know where I have to put below custom event handler code in bitrix24(self-hosted system) without changing any core file.

```
AddEventHandler('socialnetwork', 'OnBeforeSocNetGroupAdd', 'TestHandler');
function TestHandler(&$arFields) {
   $arFields['DESCRIPTION'] .= ' It is forbidden to use foul language!';
   if ($GLOBALS['USER']->GetID() == 2) {
      $GLOBALS['APPLICATION']->throwException('You cannot create groups.');
      return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If not custom module, you can put your code in two places:

1. `/bitrix/php_interface/init.php` (if there is no init.php file, create it)

or

2. If you have `local` folder in the root of the project, you can create file `init.php` in `/local/php_interface/init.php`

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works fine. But when I am trying to capture below event it will not work.Can you please what I am doing wrong here
AddEventHandler('voximplant', 'onCallInit',array('logCalInit');

 function logCalInit(&$arFields){
    file_put_contents('call-log.txt',  'test contact');
 }

Comment: try `AddEventHandler('voximplant', 'onCallInit','logCalInit'); function logCalInit(&$arFields){ file_put_contents('call-log.txt', 'test contact'); } `, you set in callback param array without classname, maybe this will help

Comment: ou, which version bitrix 24? try set event name `OnVoximplantCallInit`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but mention event not working.I am using bitrix25 17.0.10

Comment: strange, that new docs https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/scope_telephony/voximplant/events_voximplant/index.php

Comment: ou, see docs, there five params, not one: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/scope_telephony/voximplant/events_voximplant/onvoximplantcallInit.php

Comment: Thank you for your response.Today I have tried following code and it works for the onCallStart event, not for the onCallEnd event do you have any idea what I am doing wrong here.                                                    <?
AddEventHandler('voximplant', 'onCallStart',array('LogCall', 'Startcall'),101);
AddEventHandler('voximplant', 'onCallEnd',array('LogCall', 'Hangupcall'),102);
class LogCall
{
function Startcall($CALL_ID){ 
  file_put_contents('call-log1.txt',  'call end');
    }
function Hangupcall($CALL_ID){
  file_put_contents('call-log2.txt',  'call end');
    }
}
?>